# How to automatic sign in when app is launched

Tags: iphone, authentication

Most social apps do not require users to sign in every time the apps are launched, they just store users' sign in info and automatically sign in. How is this implemented? How can I store user's sign in name and password and sign in with the stored info? Is plist file the place to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

NO, use the Keychain, it is the secure storage mechanism in iOS. Check out this [tutorial from Apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Keychain is not that easy, but there is a nice implementation of it called  `SFHFKeychainUtils` [tutorial here](http://gorgando.com/blog/tag/sfhfkeychainutils)  and the [code here](http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security/)

Comment: This is really neat and easy! But I still have a question for this method: it's in fact just storing password not the user name. In the tutorial to retrieve a password, a user name is provided by NSString *userName = @"blah blah". So I guess I can use plist file to store user name and use this frame to store password?

Comment: You can, but plist's are readable. Do this create a Key for you apps user name ex. MyAppUser and store the user name like you store the password, after you retrieve the user name go ahead and us it to retrieve the password.